# How can i add will_paginate method to where condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

This is the controller where I want the paginate method to be applied.

I need the paginate method next to `@products = Product.where(value: @type.value).paginate(page: params[:page]) #But this is not working.

This is my controller    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlgGW.png

This is the error generated    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f12py.png

Is there any way I can add the method without changing a lot of things.

## This is the Error I'm getting

The @product_types variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?

Extracted source (around line #17):

```
</div>

<%= will_paginate %>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
```

Comment: @NickM take a look

Comment: Can you post  the controller action where you set the `@product_types` ivar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#will_paginate` expects a collection as argument.

```
<%= will_paginate @products %>
```